# Ocultar consola cmd a mi programa en C# con Visual Studio

Tags: c#, consola

Hasta el momento he podido cambiar ciertos aspectos desde la consola, pero no ocultarla, para que no me aparezca. Me refiero tengo un programa en modo consola, pero no quiero visualizar más la cmd, ¿Cómo podría hacer para que no me aparezca más la consola *CMD* en mi programa principal?

```
public class Program
{
    static Pool _pool = null;
    static Work _work = null;
    static uint _nonce = 0;
    static long _maxAgeTicks = 20000 * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
    static uint _batchSize = 100000;

     public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                _pool = SelectPool();
                _work = GetWork();
                while (true)
                {
                    if (_work == null || _work.Age > _maxAgeTicks)
                        _work = GetWork();

                    if (_work.FindShare(ref _nonce, _batchSize))
                    {
                        SendShare(_work.Current);
                        _work = null;
                    }
                    else
                        PrintCurrentState();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("ERROR: ");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Hit 'Enter' to try again...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }


    private static void ClearConsole()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("*****************************");
        Console.WriteLine("*** Minimal Bitcoin Miner ***");
        Console.WriteLine("*****************************");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static Pool SelectPool()
    {
        ClearConsole();
        Print("Chose a Mining Pool 'user:password@url:port' or leave empty to skip.");
        //Console.Write("Select Pool: ");
        string login = "";
        //string login = ReadLineDefault("lithander_2:foo@btcguild.com:8332");
        return new Pool(login);
    }

    private static Work GetWork()
    {
        ClearConsole();
        Print("Requesting Work from Pool...");
        Print("Server URL: " + _pool.Url.ToString());
        Print("User: " + _pool.User);
        Print("Password: " + _pool.Password);
        return _pool.GetWork();
    }

    private static void SendShare(byte[] share)
    {
        ClearConsole();
        Print("*** Found Valid Share ***");
        Print("Share: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Current));
        Print("Nonce: " + Utils.ToString(_nonce));
        Print("Hash: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Hash));
        Print("Sending Share to Pool...");
        if (_pool.SendShare(share))
            Print("Server accepted the Share!");
        else
            Print("Server declined the Share!");

        Console.Write("Hit 'Enter' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static DateTime _lastPrint = DateTime.Now;
    private static void PrintCurrentState()
    {
        ClearConsole();
        Print("Data: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Data));
        string current = Utils.ToString(_nonce);
        string max = Utils.ToString(uint.MaxValue);
        double progress = ((double)_nonce / uint.MaxValue) * 100;
        Print("Nonce: " + current + "/" + max + " " + progress.ToString("F2") + "%");
        Print("Hash: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Hash));
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - _lastPrint;
        Print("Speed: " + (int)(((_batchSize) / 1000) / span.TotalSeconds) + "Kh/s"); 
        _lastPrint = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private static void Print(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static string ReadLineDefault(string defaultValue)
    {
        //Allow Console.ReadLine with a default value
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        if (userInput == "")
            return defaultValue;
        else
            return userInput;
    }
}
```

El error con el método vbs sugerido:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3   Problem Signature
>   01:   ConsoleApplication1.exe   Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0   Problem
>   Signature 03: 5824bc4b   Problem Signature 04:    ConsoleApplication1
>   Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0   Problem Signature 06: 5824bc4b
>   Problem Signature 07: 1   Problem Signature 08:   1   Problem Signature
>   09:   System.MissingMethodException   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>   Locale ID:    1043   Additional Information 1:    0a9e   Additional
>   Information 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789   Additional
>   Information 3:    0a9e   Additional Information
>   4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma bien sencilla de eliminar la consola es al cambiar el tipo de proyecto en Visual Studio.

Etapas:

- Abre la ventana *Properties* de tu proyecto (Haz clic de la derecha a tu proyecto en el *Solution Explorer*, y escoge *Properties*)
- Cambia el valor del campo *Output Type* de *Console Application* a *Windows Application*  y salvaguarda el cambio.
- Vuelve a compilar el proyecto.

Ahora cuando ejecutes tu *exe*, verás que no abre una consola, aunque sí se está ejecutando.

Pero ojo que sin consola, tus sentencias `Console.WriteLine` pierden su sentido. Es mas, algunas sentencias, como `Console.Clear()` te van a lanzar un `IOException` con el mensaje:

> The handle is invalid.

Si no quieres consola, lo mejor es no usar la clase `Console` en tu programa.

Comment: no es solamente console.writeline sino que en otras como la funcion clearconsole()  private static void ClearConsole()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("*****************************");
            Console.WriteLine("*****");
            Console.WriteLine("*****************************");
            Console.WriteLine();
        } tengo muchas que hasta que no sean procesadas y borradas no se ejecuta la siguiente.

Comment: Mi duda es, ¿por qué sigues usando la clase `Console` en tu código si no quieres consola?

Comment: La tendré que quitar

Comment: perdona por revivir esto pero probablemente abra otro post con una consulta relacionado con tu post

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente código sirve para minimizar una ventana, con lo cual podrás entonces minimizar el CMD

```
private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr window, int nCmdShow);        

public static void minimizaWindow(IntPtr window)
{
    if (window.ToInt32() != 0)
       ShowWindow(window, SW_MINIMIZE);
}
```

Ahora bien, esto utiliza una estructura de tipo [IntPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.intptr(v=vs.110).aspx), aquí te dejo un método para obtener esto los procesos abiertos de CMD.

```
public static IntPtr getWindow(string titleName)
{
   Process[] pros = Process.GetProcesses(".");
   foreach (Process p in pros)
      if (p.MainWindowTitle.ToUpper() == (titleName.ToUpper()))
         return p.MainWindowHandle; //obtiene la primera ventana que coincida el nombre
}
```

Comment: se puede hacer tambien poniendolo como un formulario pero no se porque mi programa no funciona como deberia..

Comment: Sí estás en Windows Forms, con el this.Handle puedes obtener la estructura de tipo IntPtr de formulario, con la cual puedes usar los métodos que te puse ahí

Answer (score 1):

Lanza el programa con un script de visual basic:

1.- Creas un fichero de texto y pegas esto:

```
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
objshell.run "Nombre-del-fichero-de-tu-programa.exe",vbhide
```

2.- Lo guardas con la extensión `.vbs`

3.- Ejecutas ese script vbs sin la consola.

Comment: es interesante tambien este método pero no se si podría abreviar al lenguaje que uso yo c#

Comment: Da igual con que lenguaje se haya hecho la aplicación. Funciona incluso con un .bat. Simplemente se trata de lanzarlo de otra forma. Puedes poner un acceso directo al .vbs en vez del .exe. Es transparente para el usuario.

Comment: pues me muestra un error cuando ejecuto mi aplicacion

Comment: te pongo el error en el post

Comment: ¿Puedes pasarme el ejecutable de alguna forma para verlo? Subiéndolo a GoogleDrive o compartiéndolo en algún sitio.

Comment: el link: aqui puedes verlo https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Pw7j1oL9oBY0xnSXJycEhCaG8/view?usp=sharing De todos modos pienso que con un formulario y inicializando la funcion principal y ocultar el formulario sería más que suficiente.

Comment: En ese caso tendrías que enlazar más librerías que lo que necesita una aplicación de consola al usar el entorno de Windows Form. Déjame que prueba un rato y te digo.

Comment: A mí me va perfecto. Utiliza [este lanzador](https://sites.google.com/site/awes0mem4nfiles/lanzador.rar?attredirects=0&d=1) desde la carpeta que contiene el archivo `MiniMiner.exe`. Para saber que se está ejecutando tendrás que mirar los procesos que se están ejecutando en el administrador de tareas.

Comment: si funciona esq estaba intentando con un proyecto nuevo en la que incluia dll pero no estaba incrustada si funciona. De todos modos si con windows form no funciona creo k es por el clearconsole(); no es seguro de todos modos es una solucion usar un vbs tmb